# Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

I use Typescript with react-native and react-native web. For some reason, it doesn't recognize `styles` properties for jsx.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as Redux from 'redux'
import {Button, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

const _component: React.SFC<Props & State & DispatchProps> = (props) => (
    <View>
        <Button
            onPress={props.onPingClick(props.id)}
            title="Ping"
            color="#841584"
            style={styles.button}
        />
        <Text>{props.id}</Text>
    </View>

);
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: According to the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L6924), `Button` does not accept a `style` attribute.  What documentation did you read that suggested that it did?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen reactJs button in vanilla JS supports style property. How is it supposed to make css styles in this case?

Comment: I found an existing question with some info.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen thank you, that really helps! Can't accept your answer here, so liked few your other answers.